# How to delete a listview item based on it's ID after button click? (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, delete-row, dotnet-httpclient

So I've done some googling with minimal results, but results nonetheless. What happens is the DB has 5 entries in CalendarEvents (basically name/place/date/time etc of events in the future). I get these from my DB and display them in a listview.

Now I need an admin to be able to delete CalendarEvents based on it's row, like so:

[image]

So whenever an admin clicks the delete button, it should get the id of the listviewitem to which the button belongs (like 1-5 from the DB, id= CalendarEventsId) and then remove the correct CalendarEvent from the DB.

So far I've come up with following code:

```
private async void tbdelete_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as DependencyObject;

    while(!(item is ListViewItem))
    {
        item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    }

    var id = ((CalendarEvent) item).CalendarEventId;

    var weburidelete = "http://localhost:64288/api/calendarevents/" + id;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var res = await client.DeleteAsync(weburidelete);
}
```

I get an error with "var id = ((CalendarEvent) ... ", it says "cannot convert type "DependencyObject" to "CalendarEvent".

So for example, if the admin clicks the "delete"-button in the third row, the CalendarEvent with Id=3 (not listviewitemindex, the ID from the database) should be deleted in the database. So if I add 5 items, delete all 5 then add 5 again, I believe the IDs of the new 5 items will range from 6-10.

Does anyone know what's wrong here? Or does anyone know another way of doing this & deleting the correct listviewitem based on ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the DataContext of your button and cast it.

```
var item = sender as Button;
var data = item.DataContext;

while(!(item is ListViewItem))
{
    item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
}

var id = ((CalendarEvent)data).CalendarEventId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so all I did to make it work was use Jessica's way to get my DataContext, then remove the "while"-loop entirely. This is how the class looks now and it works!

```
private async void tbdelete_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as Button;
        var data = item.DataContext;

        var id = ((CalendarEvent)data).CalendarEventId;

        var weburidelete = "http://localhost:64288/api/calendarevents/" + id;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var res = await client.DeleteAsync(weburidelete);

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AdminAgenda), null);
    }
```